# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__FIREBASE_DEFAULTS__')

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs3

**I am unable to get firestore instance. here is my code for it i am getting the app instance but not firestore instance**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    
    export const useFirebase = async () => {
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: //,
            authDomain: //,
            databaseURL: //,
            projectId: //,
            storageBucket: //,
            messagingSenderId: //,
            appId: //,
            measurementId://
        };
    
        const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
    
        return {
            firebaseApp,
            firestore,
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your firestore is nested inside of a firebase scope here. Is it the desired behavior?

Comment: yes it is and if I console.log(firebaseApp) it also give me object.

Comment: Seems legit indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: //,
        authDomain: //,
        databaseURL: //,
        projectId: //,
        storageBucket: //,
        messagingSenderId: //,
        appId: //,
        measurementId://
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const useFirebase = {
firebaseApp,
firestore
}

export {
useFirebase
}
```

Comment: what is the difference I am using it in composables.

Comment: This code is not working for me.